# Splitting text with skillset in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Im trying to improve the performance of my cognitve search in combination with openai. Currently im indexing my documents from sharepoint and there is where my problem starts. These are large files, so i need to split them so my cognitive search gives my openai only the information back it really needs and not the full document. For that i thought about a skillset and found "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill". My index looks currently like that:

```
{
    "name" : "{{index-name}}",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_name", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_path", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_last_modified", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_size", "type": "Edm.Int64", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "pages", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false }
    ]
}
```

So now my goal is to use my skillset that if my content in a document of my index is to long it should split it into several documents, currently im stucking at this point.

```
{
    "name": "{{skillset-name}}",
    "description": "SharePoint skillset",
    "skills": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
            "name": "#1",
            "description": null,
            "context": "/document/id",
            "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
            "textSplitMode": "pages",
            "maximumPageLength": 5000,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "text",
                    "source": "/document/content"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "textItems",
                    "targetName": "pages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Split my content in an array with the name "pages", did not work. The goal is to split the content into several documents with the same filepath.

Comment: 1.  Remove the unnecessary properties from the SplitSkill, such as `description` and `sourceContext`.
2.  Change the `context` value to `/document` to indicate that the skill is applied to the entire document, not just the `id` field.
3.  Specify the `textSplitMode` as "pages" to split the content based on the specified `maximumPageLength`.
4.  Set the `inputs` section to map the `text` input to the `/document/content` field, which contains the content you want to split.
5.  Set the `outputs` section to map the resulting split pages to the `pages` field in the output document.

Comment: Thx for your help, but my output "pages" is still empty:
            "context": "/document",
            "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "text",
                    "source": "/document/content"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "textItems",
                    "targetName": "pages"
                }
            ],
            "textSplitMode": "pages",
            "maximumPageLength": 1000
        }

Comment: Hey, any progress on that?

Comment: I have the same issue,  probably related with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1398135/how-can-i-create-an-azure-cognitive-search-indexer